# Get URL from other website in CMS Page/Page builder

Tags: cms-pages, page-builder

I have two websites in my Magento site and I want to put the url from the other website in the footers by cms_page using page builder.

I know that i can get the base url using {{config path="web/secure/base_url"}} but there is a way to get the base url of the other website like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
{{store url="" _scope=store_code}}cms_page_identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following class `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`

You can access any config for any scope.

```
$config->getValue(
    'web/secure/base_url', 
    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE, 
    $websiteId
);
```

The scope can also be store for example.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but I need put the link in a cms page using page builder. So I think I cant use class or raw php code